# Почему ответ с сервера прилетает не картинка

Tags: node.js

Когда отправляю запрос на получение картинки, ответом прилетяют кряказяблы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const request = require('request-promise')
const weatherRouter = Router();

const key = '27dd86c06ee0058cdea528fcf006a5df';

weatherRouter.get('/',(req,res) => {
  const city = req.query.q;
  const icon = req.query.icon;

  request(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}`)
    .then(
      body => {
        if(icon){
          const bodyParse = JSON.parse(body)
          request(`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${bodyParse.weather[0].icon}.png`) // imgURL
            .then(image => res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png').send(image))
        } else {
          res.send(body)
        }
      }
    )
})

module.exports = weatherRouter;
```

Comment: Потому что вы забыли прописать правильный HTTP-заголовок Content-Type в ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023720

Comment: @andreymal Не помогло,теперь вместо картинки квадрат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно работать с бинарными данными как с текстом.

Правильное решение очень простое - перенаправить stream ответа openweathermap.org в stream ответа "нашего сервера":

```
weatherRouter.get('/',(req, res) => {
  const city = req.query.q;
  const needIcon = req.query.icon;

  request(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}`)
    .then((resp) => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(resp);
      const icon = weatherData.weather && weatherData.weather[0] ? weatherData.weather[0].icon : undefined;
      if (needIcon === 1 && icon) {
        request(`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${icon}.png`).pipe(res);
      } else {
        res.json(weatherData);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(406).json({ error: `${err}` });
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @IhorStoner я протупил днем, а тут вот подумал: правильнее было бы сделать запрос картинки отдельным эндпоинтом, а не отдавать и json, и картинку, одним